# Hibernate: java.lang.ClassCastException при работе с результатом query.list()

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Работаю с Hibernate. Имеется два похожих метода, один из которых выполняется успешно, а второй почему-то нет.

```
public ArrayList<Receiver> getSubscribersList() throws DatabaseHandlerException{
    Session session = SESSION_FACTORY.openSession();
    String hql = "FROM Receiver rec where rec.sender.id = :id";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("id", 5); // получаем всех подписчиков, чей отправитель имеет id = 5
    return (ArrayList<Receiver>) query.list();
}

public ArrayList<Account> getAccountsList(ArrayList<Receiver> subscribersList) throws DatabaseHandlerException{
    Session session = SESSION_FACTORY.openSession();
    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    for(Receiver rec : subscribersList){
        int id = rec.getId(); // получаем id конкретного подписчика
        String hql = "FROM Account ac join ac.receiver rec " +
                "where rec.id = :id"; // выбираем из общей БД аккаунтов все аккаунты, имеющие отношение к подписчикам переданным в параметре
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        ArrayList<Account> local = (ArrayList<Account>) query.list();
        accounts.addAll(local);
    }
    return (ArrayList<Account>) accounts;
}
```

В своём `main` я выполняю следующий код:

```
ArrayList<Receiver> receivers= dh.getSubscribersList();
for (Receiver r : receivers) {
    System.out.println(r.toString());
}
ArrayList<Account> accounts = dh.getAccountsList(receivers);
for (Account a: accounts) {
    System.out.println(a.toString());
}
```

`receivers` является `ArrayList<Receiver>`, успешно проходит цикл и я вижу в выводе нужное мне содержимое БД. А вот с `accounts` какие-то проблемы: не могу обратиться к его элементам как к `Account`, постоянно ловлю:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.pipproject.hibernate.databasepackage.Account
```

Я подозреваю, что это может быть связано с использованием `join` во втором методе, я прав? Я могу приложить также классы `Account` и `Receiver`, просто мне показалось, что дело не может быть в них и это лишь усложнит читаемость/понятность вопроса.

Comment: Для начала узнайте, что вам возвращает hibernate. query.list(); закиньте в Object поставьте на 1 строку ниже query.list(); брейкпоинт, запустите отладчик. Когда дойдете до брейка нажмите Alt+F8 и попробуйте посмотреть, что возвращает хибернейт, посмотрите какой класс, приведите к этому классу - посмотрите поля, это важная информация. И да по поводу кастомизации к листам, лучше приводить к List чем к ArrayList, хз во что там упакует хибернейт, но оно явно будет реализовывать интерфейс List

Comment: Идея правильная, только query.list() вернет лист и класс у него лист. Поэтому у этого самого листа выполните обычный гет с нулевым индексом , получите Object, а вот у него уже делайте getClass, смотрите что прилетает. Можете даже обычным системаутом. Все станет на свои места.

Comment: Разобрался. Так как у меня сложный HQL-запрос, `query.list()` вернул `List<Object[]>`, где каждый элемент массива `Object[]` является объектом класса, который маппит таблицу из запроса (в моём случае классы `Account` и `Receiver`). Во избежания повторения подобного буду использовать `Criteria` вместо HQL, как предложили в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если зрить в корень, проблема конечно же в HQL, который как явствует из его описания:

> Hibernate uses a powerful query language (HQL) that is similar in appearance to SQL. Compared with SQL, however, HQL is fully object-oriented and understands notions like inheritance, polymorphism and association.

С одной стороны HQL, действительно мощный инструмент, но имеет и некоторые неприятные особенности, которые собственно и иллюстрирует код ТС, а именно применяя HQL запросы программист может только догадываться о типе возвращаемого значения. Не зря народ в комментариях советует посмотреть в отладчике на тип возвращаемого значения и оттуда ветвиться по типу, что в общем-то ужас ужасный :)

Я лично, когда речь заходит о Hibernate почти никогда не использую HQL (ну разве что для тривиальных запросов), а стараюсь использовать альтернативный механизм `Criteria`, который позволяет точно быть уверенным в типе возвращаемого значения уже на этапе компиляции:

```
Session session = SESSION_FACTORY.openSession();
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Receiver.class).
criteria.add(Expression.eq("id",rec.getId()));
List<Receiver> receivers=criteria.list();
```

**Update**

С версии 5.2 механизм `Criteria` изменен, теперь надо примерно так:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Receiver> criteria = builder.createQuery(Receiver.class);
```

Comment: Мне стоит использовать `createCriteria()`, несмотря на то, что он помечен как `deprecated`?

Comment: см. апдейт ответа